# The image of a valuation is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, absolute-value, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I'm reading Dwork's Boook An introduction to G-Functions and I'm stuck in some part of a proposition.

We say that $|-|$ is a valuation in the field $K$ (With values in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$) if

1) $|x|=0$ if and only if $x=0$

2) For all $x,y\in K$, $|xy|=|x||y|$, and

3) $|x+y|\leq\max\{|x|,|y|\}$.

We define the valuation group of $|-|$ by $G=\text{Im}|-|$. In the proof of the proposition which I'm stucked the key is to show that $G$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but I cannot see why.

He says: '' Fix $\alpha\in K, \alpha\neq 0$ such that $|\alpha|\leq\varepsilon$'', where $\varepsilon$ is a fixed number greather than zero.

Can anyone give me any hint?

Thanks

Comment: I think there are 3 reasons why the statement is false: 1) Negative numbers are not in the image. 2) Assuming you meant $\Bbb R_{≥0}$, then $|x|=\begin{cases}1& x\neq0\\ 0 &x=0\end{cases}$ is a valuation with image $\{0,1\}$. This is nowhere dense. 3) The p-adic valuation takes on values $p^{k}$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, this is dense only at $0$. A more correct statement seems to me, if $|x|$ is not the trivial valuation then $G$ has at least one accumulation point.

Comment: The key is *not* to show the value group $G$ is dense in $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$. It’s to use the fact (from nondiscreteness of the valuation) that there is a $\beta\in K$ with $0<\vert\beta\vert<1$, and just take a suitably high power of $\beta$, $\alpha=\beta^N$, satisfying the desired inequality.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks!! I can continue with the proof of the proposition